# Installing Go on CentOS 5.x

Tags: centos, go

I want to install Go on CentOS 5.x, but Go website here http://golang.org/doc/install mentions that it is not supported.

Is there still some way to install Go Language on CentOS since CentOS is just a different flavour of Linux?

When I installed the same and ran the sample program hello.go mentioned at above website
I got the error
hello.go:3:8: import "fmt": cannot find package
package runtime: import "runtime": cannot find package

Comment: The error you're mentioning in the edited question actually doesn't look like the problem just discussed in my answer. Please double check the output of `$ go env` if it's sane.

Answer (score 5):

```
% export GOROOT=~/
% go run test.go 
test.go:3:8: import "fmt": cannot find package
package runtime: import "runtime": cannot find package
```

Not finding the "runtime" package tells you that the `$GOROOT` enviroment variable isn't set to golang root directory.
You need to set `$GOROOT`. Also you should set the `$GOPATH` variable if you use external packages (`go help gopath` for more information).

A typical setup (not specific to CentOS) would be:

```
export GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
export PATH="$GOROOT/bin:$PATH"
export GOPATH=/Users/rodowi/gocode
```

Answer (score 3):

At least for some programs it works fine. I have a production program that I compile on RHEL 6.x and deploy on 5.x and 6.x and it is working without any problems.

Edit: I used to use it under 1.0.3, but a few months ago I upgraded to "tip go" (the soon to be 1.1 version). Under 1.x it'd crash on 5.9 when accepting a tcp connection but that was fixed a few days after I reported it on the mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/18/how-to-install-go-1-1-on-centos-5

This page explains rather well what kernel primitives are missing from the CentOS-5 kernel, their impact, and possible fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid you're out of luck because of the bit too much aged kernel version of CentOS 5.x. If the go runtime uses features simply not present in that kernel, then I see no easy way how it could work.

Answer (score 0):

you could download the rpm package and begin installing locally, check below and download according to your OS:

http://pkgs.org/download/golang

or you could alternatively compile and build from source:

http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/18/how-to-install-go-1-1-on-centos-5